# Overlap callback never called

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am creating a small [space invaders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Invaders)-like game.

In `create` function I create enemies

```
enemies = game.add.group();
enemies.enableBody = true;
enemies.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.ARCADE;
enemies.x = 100;
enemies.y = 50;

for (var y = 1; y < 200; y += 50) {
    for (var x = 233; x <= 800; x += 50) {
        var enemy = enemies.create(x, y, 'enemy');
        enemy.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5);
        enemy.body.moves = false;
    }
}
```

and bullets

```
bullets = game.add.group();
bullets.enableBody = true;
bullets.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.ARCADE;
bullets.createMultiple(30, 'bullet');
bullets.setAll('anchor.x', 0.5);
bullets.setAll('anchor.y', 1);
bullets.setAll('outOfBoundsKill', true);
bullets.setAll('checkWorldBounds', true);
```

and set the overlap callback

```
game.physics.arcade.overlap(bullets, enemies, collisionHandler);
```

But, unfortunately, when the bullet overlaps an enemy, nothing happens.

Callback is

```
function collisionHandler (bullet, enemy) {
    console.log("poft");
    bullet.kill();
    enemy.kill();
}
```

Comment: In function update use: `game.physics.arcade.overlap(bullets, enemies, collisionHandler, null, this)` [example](http://phaser.io/examples/v2/arcade-physics/group-vs-group)

Comment: This is it! Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you only need to check if there is a collision between both groups, so you would choose to use the 'overlap' method that will be evaluated in the function update:

```
function update() {
   game.physics.arcade.overlap(bullets, enemies, collisionHandler, null, this);
}
```

The method receives five arguments, you can consult them [here](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.4/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.html#overlap).

And simple example of Physics Arcade: **[Group vs Group](http://phaser.io/examples/v2/arcade-physics/group-vs-group)**

Comment: This could bear an explanation, since the next person to see it might not know what problem this fixes.